# null pointer exception from DispatchAction

Tags: list, jsp, nullpointerexception, jstl, struts

I am trying to insert records into MySQL from UI but I am getting nullpointerexception in JSP page. Below are my files.

Struts File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
          "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">
<struts-config>

<action-mappings>        
        <action
            path="/inputemployee"
            forward="/pages/inputemployee.jsp"/> 

         <action  path="/db" parameter="method" type="com.pramesh.strutsdatabase.action.DataBaseAction"> 
            <forward name="success" path="/pages/insertsucess.jsp"/>
        </action>   
</action-mappings>

</struts-config>
```

inputemployee.jsp file

```
    <%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html"  prefix="html"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<script >
  function calculate(){
      document.frm.action="db.html";
      var selection=document.frm.sel.selectedIndex 

      if(selection==1){
      document.frm.method.value="insert";
      }
      document.frm.submit();  
  }
</script>

<body>

<form name ="frm">
 Enter Employee ID :<input name ="Employee ID"/>
 Enter Employee First Name :<input name ="First Name"/>
 Enter Employee Last Name :<input name ="Last Name"/>
 <select name ="sel">
      <option>Please Select</option>
      <option value="1">Insert</option>


</select> 
<input name ="method" type ="hidden" />

<input type ="button" value="Insert" onClick="calculate()"/>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Employee.java

package com.sigma.pojo;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;

public class Employee {

```
private int empId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public int getEmpId() {
    return empId;
}
public void setEmpId(int empId) {
    this.empId = empId;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee [empId=" + empId + ", firstName=" + firstName
            + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
}
```

}

EmployeeDAO.java

```
package com.sigma.employeedDAO;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.sigma.pojo.Employee;

public class EmployeeDAO {

    private Connection con = null;
    private java.sql.Statement stmt = null;
    private java.sql.PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    private ResultSet rs = null;
    private Employee e;
    private List <Employee> list= null;

    private Connection getConnection(){
        if (con==null){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "kalokando11");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {}
      }
        return con; 
    }

public List<Employee> getEmployee(){

         list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
         try {
                stmt = getConnection().createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from employee");

                    while(rs.next()){
                    frm = new Employee();
                    frm.setEmpId(rs.getInt("emp_id"));
                    frm.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));
                    frm.setLastName(rs.getString("last_name"));
                    list.add(frm);  
                }               
            } catch (SQLException e1) { 
              }
         close(); 
         return list;
    }
    public void insert(Employee e1) throws SQLException{
        pstmt = getConnection().prepareStatement("Insert into employee values (?,?,?) ");
        pstmt.setInt(1,e1.getEmpId());
        pstmt.setString(2, e1.getFirstName());
        pstmt.setString(3,e1.getLastName());
        pstmt.execute();
        close();
    }

    public void close(){
        try {
            con.close();    
            stmt.close();
            pstmt.close();
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {  
      }
    }
}
```

DataBaseAction.java

```
package com.pramesh.strutsdatabase.action;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction;

import com.sigma.employeedDAO.EmployeeDAO;
import com.sigma.pojo.Employee;

public class DataBaseAction extends DispatchAction{

public ActionForward display(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            list =dao.getEmployee();  
            request.setAttribute("employee", list);  
            return mapping.findForward("success");
    }
    public ActionForward insert(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
       Employee e1 = new Employee();

       response.setContentType("text/html");
       e1.setEmpId(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Employee ID")));
       e1.setFirstName(request.getParameter("First Name"));
       e1.setLastName(request.getParameter("Last Name"));
       EmployeeDAO dao = new EmployeeDAO();
       dao.insert(e1);
       return mapping.findForward("success");
    }

}
```

insertsucess.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Employee Added   
</body>
</html>
```

listemployee.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="com.sigma.pojo.Employee"%>
<%@page import="com.pramesh.strutsdatabase.action.DataBaseAction"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<body>
<table border=1>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Employee ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>

                <th colspan=2>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <c:forEach items="${employee}" var="user">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.empId}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.firstName}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.lastName}" /></td>               
                 </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Somehow I am getting **NullPointerException** when I call EmployeeDAO **insert** method. Can someone explain why? I can connect to database and update the table but I cannot display insertsucess page due to NullPointerExection.

Comment: why did you put blank catch block in getConnection() method in EmployeeDAO class, it may possible that you are getting an exception there and your connection object remains null?which causes NPE.

Comment: I don't have problem in connecting to database. Even my web browser shows NullPointerException, I am still able to update my database table. But I cannot go to inputsucess page and I cannot list all the data in the table.

Comment: How are you displaying employee list in inputsucess.jsp page? can you paste your code here?

Comment: I have added the methods to list all the employee in DataBaseAction.java, EmployeeDAO.java and added listemployee.jsp. I have not changed my strutsconfig file.